# Reading lines from two files in one while loop

Tags: bash

I have a file, `file1.csv` containing:

```
This
is
some
text.
```

I am using `while read line` to cycle through each line, e.g.:

```
while read line; do
    echo $line
done < file1.csv
```

I have another file, with an identical number of lines, called `file2.csv`:

```
A
B
C
D
```

The data each line corresponds to data in the first file of the same line number.

- How can I modify the while loop, such so that it can print the corresponding line from `file2.csv`?

Answer (score 15):

Use another FD.

```
while read line; do
  if ! read -u 3 line2
  then
    break
  fi
  echo "$line***$line2"
done < file1.csv 3< file2.csv
```

Answer (score 10):

You could try with the `paste` utility:

```
$ cat one
this
is
some
text
$ cat two
1
2
3
4
$ while read a b ; do echo $a -- $b ; done < <(paste one two)
this -- 1
is -- 2
some -- 3
text -- 4
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `paste` command:

```
$ paste -d, file{1,2}.csv | while IFS=, read x y; do echo "$x:$y"; done
This:A
is:B
some:C
text.:D
```

Comment: Skip the `-d` in the `paste` and skip the `IFS=,` in the `while`.  Let whitespace be your delimiter.  (Won't work if you have spaces in your data... but the above solution is broken if you have commas in your data, so same difference.)