# Read 2 file in bash with loop

Tags: bash, loops, unix

i want to make echo username inside userlist.txt, and check the main loop if username is inside chk.txt, and pause 60 second before continue the main loop

```
filename1="/home/user/userlist.txt"
while read -r  file1
do
    filename2 = "/home/user/chk.txt"
    while read -r file2
    do
      text2 = $file2
      if $file2 == "username"
         pause 60
    done < "filename2"


    text="$file1"
    txt=($file1)
    name=${txt[0]}
    echo $name
    sleep 10

done < "$filename1"
```

sorry for really bad explaination

Comment: This might help: [Reading lines from two files in one while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9885338/3776858)

Comment: but filename2 data change everytime, i need reload filename2 everytime in main loop

Comment: It looks to me like your script should work. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have some basic syntax errors.

When assigning variables, you can't have spaces around `=`. So it should be:

```
filename2=/home/user/chk.txt
text2=$file2
```

In the `if`, you're missing the `[` command to perform a test, and the `then` and `fi` keywords.

```
if [ "$file2" = "username" ]
then
    sleep 60
fi
```

There's no `pause` command, it's `sleep` (you get it right later in the script).

But if you just want to check if a word is inside a file, you don't need a loop, you can use the `grep` command.

```
if grep -q username $file2
then
    sleep 60
fi
```